# Max() function does not return largest value in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

Why does the `max()` function in Python 3.4 is giving me values smaller than expected in a list of values?

**Example 1**, where expected value is `'marco'`:

```
>>> max('zara', 'marco')
'zara'
```

**Example 2**, where expected value is `'cherries'`:

```
>>> max('apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana')
'oranges'
```

Comment: Why is marca greater than zara?

Comment: In lexicographic order o>c isn't it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings are ordered [*lexicographically*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), not by size.

- `zara` is the 'biggest' because it is last in the sort order, after `marco`:

  ```
  >>> 'zara' > 'marco'
  True
  >>> sorted(['zara', 'marco'])
  ['marco', 'zara']
  ```
- `oranges` comes after `apples`, `banana` and `cherries`.

  ```
  >>> sorted(['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'])
  ['apples', 'banana', 'cherries', 'oranges']
  ```

If you wanted the *longest* string, you need to tell `max()` to use that as the key:

```
max(sequence, key=len)
```

Demo:

```
>>> max('zara', 'marco')
'zara'
>>> max('zara', 'marco', key=len)
'marco'
>>> max('apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana')
'oranges'
>>> max('apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', key=len)
'cherries'
```

Comment: lexicographically you mean?

Comment: @Tommy: keep up, that typo was corrected ages ago! :-P

Answer (score 1):

`max` works with numbers, strings and other types, however with strings it does not work by simply looking at the size of the string - it uses **Lexical Ordering** which is the ordering you would see of words in an English dictionary.

So in your cases `zara` and `oranges` come last in the dictionary and are therefore the `max()` values.

Answer (score 1):

max uses the sort function and will give you the last word alphabetically. If you want the longest word, you need to do [len("zacra"), len("macros")....]

Comment: or you can do key = len

Answer (score 0):

Strings in max() will be compared in ASCII order, when you compare 'zare' and 'marco', the value of z in ACSII is 122, the value of m is 109, therefore zara is greater than marco. if the values of the first letter are equal, the fellowing letters will be compared until strings are equal(same strings) or one of strings greater than others.